# Iterating through a .txt file in an odd way

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

What I am trying to do is write a program that opens a .txt file with movie reviews where the rating is a number from 0-4 followed by a short review of the movie. The program then prompts the user to open a second text file with words that will be matched against the reviews and given a number value based on the review.

For example, with these two sample reviews how they would appear in the .txt file:

4 A comedy-drama of nearly epic proportions rooted in a sincere performance by the title character undergoing midlife crisis .  2 Massoud 's story is an epic , but also a tragedy , the record of a tenacious , humane fighter who was also the prisoner -LRB- and ultimately the victim -RRB- of history .

So, if I were looking for the word "epic", it would increment the count for that word by 2 (which I already have figured out) since it appears twice, and then append the values 4 and 2 to a list of ratings for that word.

How do I append those ints to a list or dictionary related to that word? Keep in mind that I need to create a new list or dicitonary key for every word in a list of words.

Please and thank you. And sorry if this was poorly worded, programming isn't my forte.

All of my code:

```
def menu_validate(prompt, min_val, max_val):
    """ produces a prompt, gets input, validates the input and returns a value. """
    while True:
        try:
            menu = int(input(prompt))
            if menu >= min_val and menu <= max_val:
                return menu
                break
            elif menu.lower == "quit" or menu.lower == "q":
                quit()
            print("You must enter a number value from {} to {}.".format(min_val, max_val))
        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a number value from {} to {}.".format(min_val, max_val))

def open_file(prompt):
    """ opens a file """
    while True:
        try:
            file_name = str(input(prompt))
            if ".txt" in file_name:
                input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
                return input_file
            else:
                input_file = open(file_name+".txt", 'r')
                return input_file
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("You must enter a valid file name. Make sure the file you would like to open is in this programs root folder.")

def make_list(file):
    lst = []
    for line in file:
        lst2 = line.split(' ')
        del lst2[-1]
        lst.append(lst2)
    return lst

def rating_list(lst):
    '''iterates through a list of lists and appends the first value in each list to a second list'''
    rating_list = []
    for list in lst:
        rating_list.append(list[0])
    return rating_list

def word_cnt(lst, word : str):
    cnt = 0
    for list in lst:
        for word in list:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

def words_list(file):
    lst = []
    for word in file:
        lst.append(word)
    return lst

##def sort(words, occurrences, avg_scores, std_dev):
##    '''sorts and prints the output'''
##    menu = menu_validate("You must choose one of the valid choices of 1, 2, 3, 4 \n        Sort Options\n    1. Sort by Avg Ascending\n    2. Sort by Avg Descending\n    3. Sort by Std Deviation Ascending\n    4. Sort by Std Deviation Descending", 1, 4)
##    print ("{}{}{}{}\n{}".format("Word", "Occurence", "Avg. Score", "Std. Dev.", "="*51))
##    if menu == 1:
##        for i in range (len(word_list)):
##            print ("{}{}{}{}".format(cnt_list.sorted[i],)

def make_odict(lst1, lst2):
    '''makes an ordered dictionary of keys/values from 2 lists of equal length'''

    dic = OrderedDict()

    for i in range (len(word_list)):
        dic[lst2[i]] = lst2[i]

    return dic        


cnt_list = []
while True:
    menu = menu_validate("1. Get sentiment for all words in a file? \nQ. Quit \n", 1, 1)
    if menu == True:
        ratings_file = open("sample.txt")
        ratings_list = make_list(ratings_file)


        word_file = open_file("Enter the name of the file with words to score \n")
        word_list = words_list(word_file)
        for word in word_list:
            cnt = word_cnt(ratings_list, word)
            cnt_list.append(word_cnt(ratings_list, word))
```

Sorry, I know it's messy and very incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
import collections

counts = collections.defaultdict(int)

word = 'epic'

counts[word] += 1
```

Obviously, you can do more with `word` than I have, but you aren't showing us any code, so ...

**EDIT**

Okay, looking at your code, I'd suggest you make the separation between rating and text explicit. Take this:

```
def make_list(file):
    lst = []
    for line in file:
        lst2 = line.split(' ')
        del lst2[-1]
        lst.append(lst2)
    return lst
```

And convert it to this:

```
def parse_ratings(file):
    """
    Given a file of lines, each with a numeric rating at the start,
    parse the lines into score/text tuples, one per line. Return the
    list of parsed tuples.
    """
    ratings = []
    for line in file:
        text = line.strip().split()
        if text:
            score = text[0]
            ratings.append((score,text[1:]))
    return ratings
```

Then you can compute both values together:

```
def match_reviews(word, ratings):
    cnt = 0
    scores = []

    for score,text in ratings:
        n = text.count(word)
        if n:
            cnt += n
            scores.append(score)

    return (cnt, scores)
```

Comment: I've got the count part figured out. I need to be able to iterate through the .txt file and whenever the word the program is looking for appears, it should append the integer preceding that word to a list.

Comment: Okay, I've added some code that may help. I think you need to start treating your data more formally. Separate the score from the text, and then keep them in their official positions afterwards. You'll always know what's what.